# javascript regex replace multiline strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex replace running in my javascript that looks likes this,

```
this.set('activity', activity.replace(/{(object)}(.*?){\/\1}/gi, '<a href="' + object_link + '" class="' + linkClass + '">$2</a>'));
this.set('activity', activity.replace(/{(object)}(.*?){\/\1}/gi, '<a href="' + object_link + '" class="' + linkClass + '">$2</a>'));
```

The above works great when the strings look something like this,

```
{blockquote}{object}Joe Bloggs{/object} did something great!{/blockquote}
```

However if the strings is multi-line, i.e

```
{blockquote}{object}Joe Bloggs{/object} did something great  
and it broke on to two lines{/blockquote}
```

I thought I would be able to just add the multiline check in to my regExp, like so,

```
this.set('activity', activity.replace(/{(object)}(.*?){\/\1}/gmi, '<a href="' + object_link + '" class="' + linkClass + '">$2</a>'));
this.set('activity', activity.replace(/{(object)}(.*?){\/\1}/gmi, '<a href="' + object_link + '" class="' + linkClass + '">$2</a>'));
```

But it does not parse out the {object} and {blockquotes} as it does for single line of text

Any ideas why?

Comment: instead `.` use `[\S\s]`

Comment: sorry where would that go?

Comment: Use `[^]` to match any symbol in JS (inside BMP plane).

Comment: Try this

`this.set('activity', activity.replace(/{(object)}([\s\S]*?){\/\1}/gi, '<a href="' + object_link + '" class="' + linkClass + '">$2</a>'));
`

try you test string here: [Regex101][1]


  [1]: https://regex101.com/r/iL2iH0/1